# Print address of cython variable

Tags: cython

I am simply trying to print the address of cython variable but i can not get around the error message:

```
cdef int myvar
print &myvar
```

throws

```
Cannot convert 'int *' to Python object
```

What do i need to do to print the address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After thinking a while the answer is as simple as the question:

```
cdef int myvar
print "{0:x}".format(<unsigned int>&myvar)
```

Comment: In case you get `error: cast loses precision` try a cast to `<unsinged long>` instead

Comment: what if my c++ object is not of primary type, but a c++ class object?

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic, but shouldnt there be no difference, as the start adress of an object will also be retrieved with the & operator?

Comment: @maggie thanks you are right! I used long though, to hold enough big address